# Google map compass error with 0.67dp view

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a view and a google map fragment with compass.

Map and Compass works fine. The problem is, it is MOVING. Moving to the north.
I got only camera position of google map, and set bearing, and set this class to google map to set bearing(rotation) of the map.

My first thought was, compass is the reason of this problem. But it wasn't. After remove bearing(), map is still MOVING smoothly to the north.

Finally, I found the reason. 0.67dp view above of google map was the problem. After change 0.67dp to 1dp, the map is not moving.

But I cannot understand why this thing happens. 0.67dp height is real problem? And why? Or there is another secret reason for this?

Does anybody can help me to explain why this thing happens?

Below is all of my code.

**MapActivity.java**

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private LatLng currentPoint = new LatLng(37.49349, 127.013958);
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private Sensor magnetometer;
    private GoogleMap gmap = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        initGoogleMap();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void initGoogleMap() {
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flGoogleMap, supportMapFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();

        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                gmap = map;
                showMyPosition();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showMyPosition() {
        gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPoint, 18));
    }

    private float[] mGravity;
    private float[] mGeomagnetic;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values;
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;
        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                float azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
                // float pitch = orientation[1];
                // float roll = orientation[2];

                float destAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(azimut);
                showMapDirection(destAngle);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showMapDirection(float bearing) {
        if (gmap == null) {
            return;
        }
        CameraPosition oldPos = gmap.getCameraPosition();
        if (oldPos == null) {
            return;
        }
        //CameraPosition pos = CameraPosition.builder(oldPos).bearing(bearing).build();
        // FIXME: After remove bearing, it still moving
        CameraPosition pos = CameraPosition.builder(oldPos).build();
        gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos));
    }

}
```

**activity_map.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.67dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_divider" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flGoogleMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```